# Regex: Any pattern present more than once should not be a match

Tags: regex

String to be matched: `first-3-days`

Regex: `first-[3,6]-days`

This Regex matches the string as expected. But, if there are any other characters before or after the given string, that will be an invalid match for me. For instance,

`hellofirst-3-days` - is invalid match

`first-3daysfirst-3-days` - is invalid match

Any hints please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to match `3` or `6` and not `,`. If that is true, you should use `[36]` and not `[3,6]`

You can use word boundaries:

```
\bfirst-[36]-days\b
```

Or if your input string should start from `first` and end with `days` you can use start/end string specifiers, e.g.:

```
^first-[36]-days$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kirill. For others, https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html.

Comment: Just an extension, if the string is `first-3-days\nhello`, I see that this passes through. Can we restrict this?

Comment: @Chaitanya, if your input string must be like this: `first-`, then `3` or `6`, then `-days`, you can use `^` and `$` specifiers, as per my second regex